# Why mysql program hangs(deadlock)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am struggling more than one day on dealing with a mysql hangs(deadlock). In below testcase, I will try to create the database first if it doesn't exist and try to create a table if it doesn't exist too. Then I do a query on the table. Each time I execute the SQL command, I strictly close the cursor. But the program still hangs. I have found two workarounds. 1) close the connection after creating the database and create a new connection. 2) call commit() after the query.

The two workarounds works good but they make me more confused. As my understanding, it's ok to keep connection if the cursors are closed in time and commit() are called after each change. And also, there is no reason to call commit() after query.

So my two workarounds even destroyed my understanding of database operation. I do need some help to point out what's wrong with the program basically.... Just give me some light...

Thanks very much!

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import MySQLdb

def NewConnectToMySQL():
    conn = MySQLdb.Connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword")
    return conn

def CreateDBIfNotExists(conn):
    sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb"

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    cur.close()

    conn.select_db("testdb")
    conn.commit()

    """workaround-1"""
    #conn.close()
    #conn = NewConnectToMySQL()
    #conn.select_db("testdb")
    return conn

def CreateTableIfNotExists(conn):
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER, name TEXT)"  

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    cur.close()

    conn.commit()

def QueryName(conn, name):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = '%s'" % name

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    info = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    """workaround-2"""
    #conn.commit()

    return info

conn1 = NewConnectToMySQL()
CreateDBIfNotExists(conn1)

CreateTableIfNotExists(conn1)

QueryName(conn1, "tom")

conn2 = NewConnectToMySQL()
CreateDBIfNotExists(conn2)
CreateTableIfNotExists(conn2) #hangs here!!!!!!!!!!
```

Here is the output of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST when hangs.

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
    -> ;
+-----+------+-----------+--------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db     | Command | Time | State                           | Info                                                       |
+-----+------+-----------+--------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 720 | root | localhost | testdb | Sleep   |   96 |                                 | NULL                                                       |
| 721 | root | localhost | testdb | Query   |   96 | Waiting for table metadata lock | CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER, name TEXT) |
| 727 | root | localhost | NULL   | Query   |    0 | NULL                            | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                      |
+-----+------+-----------+--------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` while your query hangs and post  the results?

Comment: I modified the post with the output of "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"...

Comment: I am guessing that AUTOCOMMIT is set to false, which means the SELECT query opens a transaction and does not close it. The transaction will lock any DDL operation (such as `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`), until closed. Workaround 1 closes the transaction by closing the connection, while 2 does it by committing. cur.close() does not close the transaction.

Comment: @Galz, yes, the MySQL client for Python sets autocommit to false by default. It's the developer's responsibility to commit promptly.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Thanks! Mystery solved then, I believe.